# How can I find out in which direction user slide the Panorama? (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I have a Panorama Page. How can I find out in which side user slide the Panorama? I need to know the direction of sliding

```
 void DialogPanorama_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedIndex = this.DialogPanorama.SelectedIndex;
            int count = this.DialogPanorama.Items.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                {
                    FeedItemViewModel curItem = this.DialogPanorama.Items[i] as FeedItemViewModel;
                    if (curItem != null)
                    {
                        if (Math.Abs(i - selectedIndex) > 1 && Math.Abs(Math.Abs(i - selectedIndex) - count) > 1)
                        {
                            curItem.ItemVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            curItem.ItemVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Update:**

I think it should be done using this:

```
 Point startPoint = e.ManipulationOrigin;
            MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();
```

Comment: If you know what is the page before the slide and after the slide, you can easily deduce the direction of the slide, maybe i don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: this is much difficult then find out the slide dirrection because the number of pages changes dinamicaly

Comment: ok, but i post a code, maybe it will help you a little bit :)

Answer (score 3):

What i'll do is to get the coordinate of the touch at 2 differents moment (short).
If the abscissa of the coordinate B is higher than the abscissa of the coordinate A, then the user want to slide to the left.
If the abscissa of the cordinate B is lowest thant the abscissa of the coordinate A, then the user want to slide to the right.

Have a look here (Getting the touch position):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197572.aspx

---

Edit other way:

Easy way to deduce the direction of the slide:

```
    private void Panorama_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OldPage = ActualPage;
        ActualPage = panorama.SelectedIndex;
        MessageBox.Show("Old page: " + OldPage + "\n Actual Page: " + ActualPage);
        if (OldPage < ActualPage)
            MessageBox.Show("Direction of the slide: Right");
        else if (OldPage > ActualPage)
            MessageBox.Show("Direction of the slide: Left");
        // else if( some other specific condition...)

    }



    private int OldPage { get; set; }
    private int ActualPage { get; set; }
```

Comment: it is not exactly that I need

Comment: Hi, i am also searching for same problem.Above example only shows the true and false value but the main question is how to find out the flow direction of panorama?left to right or right to left.